# User Dashboards Examples

Tags: user-experience

Is there a place I can go and look at some UX templates for user dashboards?  Show a customer's orders history, address, stuff like that?

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure if you meant a dashboard for the user or one used by the business showing user data. These are the latter - they may give you some inspiration, however, regardless of which you are looking for.

[Business Porn: The Company Dashboard](http://www.mindscape.co.nz/staff/johndaniel/index.php/2010/03/business-porn-the-company-dashboard/)

[Fun with LCDs](http://jon.oxer.com.au/blog/id/360)

Comment: I'm referring to one for a user.  He logs into a website, sees his order history, stuff like that.  Just like you would see, if, say, you logged into amazon and clicked on "my account"

Answer (score 1):

Still not quite what you're looking for, but closer:
[Information Dashboards](http://uipatternfactory.com/p=information-dashboard/)